# How to initialize gridlayoutmanager in fragment which uses cardview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, cardview, gridlayoutmanager

I am new with using GridLayoutManager and need some help with its initializing. I created test version of recyclerview with cardview and it worked perfectly when my code was placed in mainactivity. But now when I copied it to main project to my HomeFragment there was shown errors with GridLayout manager initializing.

my code in HomeFragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var charItem: ArrayList<CharItem>? = null
private var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager? = null
private var alphaAdapters: AlphaAdapters? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    applicationContext
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_item)
    gridLayoutManager =
        GridLayoutManager(**applicationContext**, 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recyclerView?.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    recyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    charItem = ArrayList()
    charItem = setAlphas()
    alphaAdapters = AlphaAdapters(**applicationContext,** charItem!!)
    recyclerView?.adapter = alphaAdapters

}

private fun setAlphas(): ArrayList<CharItem> {

    var arrayList: ArrayList<CharItem> = ArrayList()

    arrayList.add(CharItem(R.drawable.image_3__2_, R.drawable.ic_nail,"Nail 
услуги")).....

}
```

Problem is in application context

So the problem is in HomeFragment code especially with ApplicationContext in GridLayoutManager. What is the solution? Is there anything which can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment lifecycle is slightly different from activity, most notably you have to break down view initialization because it has separate lifecycle (unlike activity it can be detached and undergo view destruction while leaving fragment itself intact). For that you should use `onViewCreated` method and implement `onDestroyView` to clear view references.

Best practice inside fragment to obtain context is to use `requireContext()` then you can proceed to pull `applicationContext` from it if needed.

Also fragment doesn't have `setContentView` method. You have to either override `onCreateView` method or if you're using static layout you can use [`Fragment (int contentLayoutId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#Fragment(int)) constructor instead:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.activity_main) {
    private var alphaAdapters: AlphaAdapters? = null
    private var charItem: ArrayList<CharItem>? = null

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager? = null

    // initialize adapter in onCreate, it's unaffected by views state
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        charItem = ArrayList()
        charItem = setAlphas()
        alphaAdapters = AlphaAdapters(requireContext(), charItem!!)
    }

    // initialize recyclerView and layout manager
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_item).also {
            it.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
            it.setHasFixedSize(true)
            it.adapter = alphaAdapters
        }
   }

    // release recyclerView and layout manager
   override fun onDestroyView() {
       super.onDestroyView()
       recyclerView?.adapter = null
       recyclerView = null
       gridLayoutManager = null
   }

   private fun setAlphas(): ArrayList<CharItem> {
       // (....)
   }
}
```

Comment: I just placed in triangle brackets findViewById<RecyclerView> and it worked perfectly! Thank you very match!